# What is the 'transformation' tag for?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

Looking at the tags, I see that [transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) tag is the first tag without a tag wiki. Upon further investigation I see questions that are barely related. Some of them are geometry related, some are to do with linear algebra and others are even to do with integration. Is this tag really constructive?

Comment: I posted about this tag [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17242/147263), but I don't mind the issue getting more attention, given how widely the tag is used.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a tag excerpt pointing out the ambiguity of the term, and suggesting alternatives. I think that as long as the tag is used together with another tag, it is not a problem: e.g., in the combination 
[probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions) [transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) the second tag adds some information.

I suggest editing the [questions with no other tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btransformation%5D+is%3Aq): there are about 50 of those, and they appear at the beginning of this list. In some cases the tag can be replaced by others, in others it can be kept because addition of other tags clarifies the meaning. And many of those questions could use a better title too.

I can also imagine that creating a tag like [geometric-transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-transformations) may be helpful. So far we have [rotations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotations) and [rigid-transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rigid-transformations), but there are also scaling and shear deformations...

Comment: I would personally prefer (affine-transformations) to (geometric-transformations) for what you describe in the last paragraph.